# Select first word of list of strings and concat last char of the rest of items on list in linq

Tags: c#, python, linq, python-2.7, python-2.x

Having a python code like:

```
reads = ['ACCGA', 'CCGAA', 'CGAAG', 'GAAGC', 'AAGCT']
k=len(reads[0])
rest = ""
for r in reads[1:]:
    rest += (r[k-1:])
print reads[0] + rest
```

The code gets first item on list `ACCGA` then concats the last char of each item on the rest of the list like

```
the rest = ['CCGAA', 'CGAAG', 'GAAGC', 'AAGCT']
```

and take `'CCGA`**A**`', 'CGAA`**G**`', 'GAAG`**C**`', 'AAGC`**T**'

so result `ACCGA` + **A** `+` **G** `+` **C** `+` **T**

`result = ACCGAAGCT`

What would be the way to do it on using linq?

I understand that We can select first item doing

```
string result = myList.Select(arr => arr.FirstOrDefault());
```

then to concat the rest

```
var rest = from p in myList.Items
                 where ....  
                select p;
```

Do not know how to complete it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  SO is not a coding service.  Show us your linq code (per the mcve page), and we'll take a shot at fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new []{"ACCGA", "CCGAA", "CGAAG", "GAAGC", "AAGCT"}.Aggregate((a,b)=>a+b.Last())
```

For very large arrays, this would perform better:

```
var arr=new []{"ACCGA", "CCGAA", "CGAAG", "GAAGC", "AAGCT"};
var builder=new StringBuilder(arr.First());
var res=arr.Skip(1).Aggregate(builder,(a,b)=>a.Append(b.Last())).ToString();
```

For Lists or Arrays that are very large (Any IEnumerable that implements a native Count/Length), this would perform slightly better yet, preallocating the size of the StringBuilder, feel free to remove the -1 to waste an extra byte of memory in exchange for one less decrement:

```
var arr=new []{"ACCGA", "CCGAA", "CGAAG", "GAAGC", "AAGCT"};
var builder=new StringBuilder(arr.First(),arr.First().Length+arr.Length-1);
var res=arr.Skip(1).Aggregate(builder,(a,b)=>a.Append(b.Last())).ToString();
```

Here's a faster version, if you really need the extra speed:

```
var arr=new []{"ACCGA", "CCGAA", "CGAAG", "GAAGC", "AAGCT"};
var builder=new StringBuilder(arr.First(),arr.First().Length+arr.Length-1);
var res=arr.Skip(1).Aggregate(builder,(a,b)=>a.Append(b[b.Length-1])).ToString();
```

Even faster:

```
var res=arr[0].Substring(0,arr[0].Length-1)+String.Join("",arr.Select(b=>b[b.Length-1]));
```

And even more faster:

```
var arr=Enumerable.Range(0,1000000).Select(x=>"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ").ToArray();
var len=arr.Length;
var builder=new StringBuilder(arr[0],arr[0].Length+len-1);
for(var x=1;x<len;x++)
{
  builder.Append(arr[x][arr[x].Length-1]);
}
var res=builder.ToString();
```

Comment: This is very nice answer, aggregate would be very efficent as it reads the array only once right?

Comment: I don't think there will be a shorter one ;-)

Comment: It only reads the array once, but it does a string concatenation function for each iteration, so as the number of elements grows, the performance gets worse at an exponential rate.  There is faster methods for large arrays, but this will work in most reasonable cases.

Comment: Finally, could you tell what to do on very large arrays?, what method would you follow?

Comment: I would use the last thing I posted for very large arrays.  If it doesn't perform adequately, then look for other solutions.

Comment: "And even more faster" runs in 0.012 seconds for 1,000,000 strings.  That's plenty fast for my common use.  Normally, I'd just use the very first one I had however, and it took 378 seconds to do 1,000,000 strings.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need linq for it?

Basically all you need is one line of python code:

```
result = reads[0] + ''.join([item[-1] for item in reads[1:]])
```

Comment: But I would like to use C#, and specially linq

Comment: Then you should probably remove the python tag

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
string[] reads = new string[] { "ACCGA", "CCGAA", "CGAAG", "GAAGC", "AAGCT" };
string firstword = reads[0];
reads.Where(r => !r.Equals(firstword)).ToList().ForEach(s => firstword = firstword + s.Last());
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do it, but this should do the trick using overload of `string` ctor that excepts `char[]` :

```
string[] myList = {"ACCGA", "CCGAA", "CGAAG", "GAAGC", "AAGCT"};

string result = myList[0] + new String(myList.Where(s=> s != myList[0]).Select(s2=> s2.Last()).ToArray());
```

Output : `ACCGAAGCT`

Comment: This is not correct. The op wants to concat the first element to the last char of each element from the rest

Comment: @JackyNguyen oh thank you, i misunderstood the question. Updated my answer